# Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

Tags: 14.10, qt

I am getting this error when I tried to run [APK Studio](https://apkstudio.codeplex.com/) in my Ubuntu 14.10

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: xcb (from /home/user-name/apkstudio-2.0.3b-ubuntu-linux/./platforms).

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted
```

I have a working QT Creator/ Ubuntu SDK software, and all dependencies are installed which is mentioned [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git).

My xcb locate output, `locate libxcb.so.1`

```
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this error ?

Comment: An answer to another question suggests a possible way forward on this problem: https://askubuntu.com/a/1054691/80644