# Could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb": TexMaker

Tags: qt

I am trying to run TexMaker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but every time I try to do so I get the following error:

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load
the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have tried the solution presented [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without) but no luck.

The ldd command to resolve dependencies can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/Ldfejmxr)

and the strace output [here](https://pastebin.com/v0Uy41wZ)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.