# Can't launch some installed apps Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: software-installation

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 and can't launch Gparted nor Krusader. Tried removing and installing from Terminal and App Store, but to no avail. Other apps work fine. Tried installing VLC - it works OK.

I'm new to Linux so I have no clue what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the fresh install of Ubuntu was missing some Qt5 libraries, which I had to install.

The following post was helpful:
[“Failed to load platform plugin ”xcb“ ” while launching qt5 app on linux without qt installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without)

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly: Linux is case-sensitive. "`gparted`" and "`Gparted`" are not the same program name, and only the first is right.

To see if a package ( which contains a program AND the program's ancillary files) is installed, use the terminal command `dpkg -l packagename` (`dpkg -l gparted`). To see a list of the files installed by a package use the terminal command `dpkg -L packagename` (`dpkg -L gparted`).

To get from a file on your system back to the package that installed it, use the terminal command `dpkg -S filename` (`dpkg -S /bin/bash` or `dpkg -S $(type -p bash)` ).

Comment: After running the commands both show up as being installed and both have files associated with them. But what does that tell me? I did not understand the purpose of your last comment - `dpkg -S filename` - what should I use that for? I understand it would tell me which package a file belongs to, but how does that help me troubleshoot the problem?